# Is it correct and natural to say "be at one's training " meaning to at a places where one's training takes place?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *be at a training session* meaning to at a places where one's training takes place? For example:

> I can't talk at the moment because I'm **at my training**.

If it doesn't sound right, does any of the following sound more natural?

> I can't talk at the moment because I'm **in my training**.
>
> I can't talk at the moment because I'm **at my training session**.
>
> I can't talk at the moment because I'm **in my training session**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At my training" is fine.

*Training* is a noun, and like many nouns for activities (such as the names of sports) it is very flexible and can refer to a single session, a place you go to for the activity, or an activity you attend regularly. For example, "I'm going to football" could mean you are going to the place you regularly go to play football; likewise, "I'm at football" could mean you are at the place you go to play football.

The use of "my" suggests that the person you are speaking to is already aware that you are taking part in some training. If you add "session" to the end, it sounds like you have previously made them aware of a particular session, or perhaps that the training only consists of one session.

Your alternative "*in* my training" is also fine, but would mean you are actually engaged in the session at that moment, rather than just "at" the place it is taking place. "In training" does have another use, which can refer to being engaged in *ongoing* training (not necessarily at that moment), for example "I'm in training to be a teacher".

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! Could you please clearify one more thing? Would it be as correct to say "I am at training" or "I am in training"?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Either are fine in context. "At training" is the most 'familiar' - that is to say it assumes the person you are speaking to is familiar with the training you are doing.

Comment: _In training for_ usually implies _preparing oneself for a forthcoming event_ (such as a race).

Comment: @KateBunting in context, yes. But if you asked a teacher if they were qualified and they said "I'm in training" you'd assume they meant teacher training, not that they were training for the London marathon.